# Working with android screen layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling to come to grips with android layouts, firstly can anyone point me to a good basic tutorial on working with the layouts on screen.  I understand the concepts when i read the google layout dev ref, but come to practice and I don't quite get it.

I have the below layout that I am trying to replicate in an Android screen, I believe I need to nest different layouts within others, but I can't quite get what I have to look like this:
http://screencast.com/t/GFw7OSzvbmX

Any suggestions on code out there similar and also the tutorials to get me going would be great thx

Comment: use linear and relative layout combination.. that will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TextView,Button,ImageView as child and use LinearLayout as parent with weight which handle area allocation child content :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.40">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview"/>
             <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @makapaka,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(Black - LinearLayout Vertical )
(Red - LinearLayout Horizontal )
(Green - ImageView ) 
(Yellow - TextView )
(Brown - Button )

Visualize like this first . Then write your xml .